# Ruby version >= X is incompatible with current version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have rbenv installed on my system and am trying to run the standard `bundle install` command within my ruby application now.  I'm getting the following error though:

`activesupport-5.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.2, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 1.9.3p484`

I've checked everything on my end and am unsure where it's getting the old version of ruby `1.9.3...` since I have `2.3.0` installed:

```
> rbenv versions
    system
  * 2.3.0 (set by /neo-main/.ruby-version)

> ruby --version
  ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [i686-linux]

> echo $PATH
  /root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I've rebooted just to make sure there wasn't something stuck in memory or whatever too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check where your `bundle` command is coming from; it's probably outside rbenv. Do a `gem install bundler` and then rerun `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to pick up the new shim.

Comment: Total lifesaver!  I was going crazy!

Comment: Of course I was able to deduce the answer with my massive brain without it ever having happened to me before.  *cough*

Comment: Can't thank you enough.